# How do you access activities from the public activity gem inside the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was trying to figure out how to get to activities in the rails console when using the public activity gem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get into the rails console by doing

```
rails c
```

and then

```
PublicActivity::Activity.all
```